# Hiding private details from open source projects

Tags: c#

I have a .net github project that is basically a wrapper around a web API. In the test project, I am calling to the API using an API key. I need to keep this key private, how do I accomplish this in a visual studio project?

In some other projects, like python, I can have git ignore the file (`config.py`) and use something like `config.example.py`. But in visual studio's case, the project will not compile because of the missing file `Config.cs`. What is the proper way to solve this? I'm thinking of using this same method of ignoring the file and have them execute a build script that should rename `Config.example.cs` to `Config.cs`?

Comment: Why do you want to store the config in a code file? A datafile is a much better idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the perfect for .config files. Depending on whether its a web or console application, you will have a web.config or app.config file in your project.

You can use the `appSettings` section to store your API key.

To make things even easier, you can actually have this section read from another file, ie: specialappsettings.config and then just ignore that single file from your repository.

Modify your **web.config** (or **app.config**):

```
<configuration>
<appSettings file="specialappsettings.config">
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<!-- standard web settings go here -->
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Create a new **specialappsettings.config** file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="APIKey" value="YourApiKeyValue" />
<add key="AnotherKey" value="AnotherValue" />
</appSettings>
```

This can be accessed in your code via:

```
var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
```

Notes:

- You can keep your settings within the original web.config file as
  well but this lets you ignore just the specific settings file from
  your git repository without affecting the rest of the project's
  necessary configuration details.
- The same "key" can be saved in
  either file however the external file will override the original
  web.config file value.

Comment: So which one will their api key be in and which one will I ignore?

Comment: I'd advise putting the API key and specific details like that in a separate file (create appsettings.config) using the code above. Then ignore the `appsettings.config` file from your git repository. This will let the rest of the application work just fine since the web.config file is necessary to run, but wont have specific details like this.

Comment: Is there a way to share a `.config` file across several projects in a solution?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury Yes, just point to the same `specialappsettings.config` file in the `app.config` files, it's a relative path so you can move it to a parent folder and use `<appSettings file="../specialappsettings.config">` -- that being said, this is a rather outdated method now with the new .NET releases so I suggest looking at the new configuration APIs instead.

Comment: @ManiGandham Are you talking about the Secret Manager Tool for .NET Core, or some other new best practice for .NET Framework?

Comment: @lordcheeto Yes, that's one option that makes it easy. You can also use something like Hashicorp Vault or any of the cloud vendor key-management systems to write a small app yourself, or try something like https://www.envkey.com

Comment: @ManiGandham Thanks! Decided to port my app to Azure Functions, so using their built in app setting paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `App.config` file for a project.  It will be copied to `<application>.exe.config` when you compile it.  Users can edit that config file as needed.

In that config file, you can add your API keys:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="APIKey" value="12345"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then you can access it from your code using `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`:

```
string apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use  .config files instead of having secret keys hardcoded in sources.

More info [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [step-by-step guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815786)

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="SecretKey" value="0" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>


var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SecretKey");
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can store the key outside of the Config.cs file and load it at run time.

Bonus, other people using your code won't have to recompile the project to change to their API key.